# Cannot mount/see/access USB-device - ttyUSB0

Tags: usb, mount, udev, gps

I am trying to connect to a GPS sport watch (similar to Garmin watches). I am running Ubuntu 12.04, 64bit. Ideally, I would like to connect the watch to one of the OS sport softwares like turtle sport or pytrainer. Currently, I however cannot even access the raw data saved on the device itself.

When I plug in the watch via a USB cable, it seems to be recognized, as it is listed in the output of

```
#lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x Composite Device
```

Or more detailed

```
#lsub -v
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x Composite Device
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
bLength                18
bDescriptorType         1
bcdUSB               2.00
bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
bDeviceSubClass         0 
bDeviceProtocol         0 
bMaxPacketSize0        64
idVendor           0x10c4 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc.
idProduct          0xea60 CP210x Composite Device
bcdDevice            1.00
iManufacturer           1 
iProduct                2 
iSerial                 3 
bNumConfigurations      1
Configuration Descriptor:
bLength                 9
bDescriptorType         2
wTotalLength           32
bNumInterfaces          1
bConfigurationValue     1
iConfiguration          0 
bmAttributes         0x80
  (Bus Powered)
MaxPower              100mA
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        0
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           2
  bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
  bInterfaceSubClass      0 
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              2 
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
    bInterval               0
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
    bInterval               0
```

The watch signals that the battery is being loaded, so it seems to get some sort of signal from the connection.

However, I can neither access the device nor does it appear in nautilus. The relevant output of dmesg looks as follows:

```
[   18.949280] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[   18.949952] USB Serial support registered for generic
[   18.950933] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[   18.950936] usbserial: USB Serial Driver core
[   18.954875] USB Serial support registered for cp210x
[   18.954911] cp210x 2-5:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[   19.111293] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNEB] enabled at IRQ 18
[   19.111313] nvidia 0000:06:00.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNEB] -> GSI 18 (level, low) -    > IRQ 18
[   19.111322] nvidia 0000:06:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   19.111327] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:06:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[   19.111531] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  173.14.35  Fri Jun  8     00:07:59 PDT 2012
[   19.128225] usb 2-5: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci_hcd
[   19.335214] usb 2-5: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   19.335235] usbcore: registered new interface driver cp210x
[   19.335237] cp210x: v0.09:Silicon Labs CP210x RS232 serial adaptor driver
```

The corresponding driver seems to be loaded:

```
#lsmod |grep cp210x
cp210x                 21898  0 
usbserial              47077  1 cp210x
```

It also seems as if a device was created

```
#ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Dec 31 14:08 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

So - as far as my understanding goes (probably not very far, really), it seems to load and attach the driver correctly. However, after the dmesg output shown above, I see some code that I don't quite understand

```
[   19.735193] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[   19.735547] EXT3-fs (sdb2): using internal journal
[   19.735552] EXT3-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
[   20.591773] vesafb: mode is 1280x1024x32, linelength=5120, pages=0
[   20.591777] vesafb: scrolling: redraw
[   20.591780] vesafb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
[   20.593323] vesafb: framebuffer at 0xd0000000, mapped to 0xffffc90010a80000, using 5120k, total 5120k
[   20.593576] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x64
[   20.593604] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
[   23.124371] init: failsafe main process (948) killed by TERM signal
[   23.240243] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   23.240289] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   23.240291] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   23.240295] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   23.240297] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   23.240644] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   23.243393] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   23.245909] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   23.245914] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   23.267923] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   23.267930] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   23.267932] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   23.285082] type=1400 audit(1356962831.181:5): apparmor="STATUS"     operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=1033     comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.287852] type=1400 audit(1356962831.181:6): apparmor="STATUS"         operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1033 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.297740] type=1400 audit(1356962831.193:7): apparmor="STATUS"       operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1054 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.301207] type=1400 audit(1356962831.197:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session-wrapper" pid=1053 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.310950] type=1400 audit(1356962831.205:9): apparmor="STATUS"     operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1054 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.312250] type=1400 audit(1356962831.209:10): apparmor="STATUS"     operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1054     comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.316800] type=1400 audit(1356962831.213:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=1060 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.317349] type=1400 audit(1356962831.213:12): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*" pid=1060 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.321411] type=1400 audit(1356962831.217:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=1062 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.324683] type=1400 audit(1356962831.221:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1062 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.355073] forcedeth 0000:00:08.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[   33.752029] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[   81.464968] usb 2-5: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   81.465125] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[   81.465140] cp210x 2-5:1.0: device disconnected
[   89.452023] usb 2-5: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci_hcd
[   89.682827] cp210x 2-5:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[   89.860039] usb 2-5: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci_hcd
[   90.066722] usb 2-5: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  165.960043] ata6: EH in SWNCQ mode,QC:qc_active 0x13F sactive 0x13F
[  165.960048] ata6: SWNCQ:qc_active 0x13A defer_bits 0x5 last_issue_tag 0x1
[  165.960049]   dhfis 0x13A dmafis 0x130 sdbfis 0xC5
[  165.960052] ata6: ATA_REG 0x41 ERR_REG 0x0
[  165.960054] ata6: tag : dhfis dmafis sdbfis sactive
[  165.960056] ata6: tag 0x1: 1 0 0 1  
[  165.960059] ata6: tag 0x3: 1 0 0 1  
[  165.960060] ata6: tag 0x4: 1 1 0 1  
[  165.960062] ata6: tag 0x5: 1 1 0 1  
[  165.960064] ata6: tag 0x8: 1 1 0 1  
[  165.960074] ata6.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x13f SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[  165.960076] ata6.00: Ata error. fis:0x21
[  165.960079] ata6.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  165.960085] ata6.00: cmd 60/08:00:67:40:4b/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
[  165.960086]          res 41/00:08:db:f5:30/00:00:08:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  165.960089] ata6.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  165.960091] ata6.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  165.960096] ata6.00: cmd 60/08:08:db:f5:30/00:00:08:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 4096 in
[  165.960097]          res 41/00:08:db:f5:30/00:00:08:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  165.960100] ata6.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  165.960102] ata6.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  165.960107] ata6.00: cmd 60/08:10:ef:bc:11/00:00:01:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 4096 in
[  165.960108]          res 41/00:08:db:f5:30/00:00:08:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  165.960110] ata6.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  165.960112] ata6.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  165.960117] ata6.00: cmd 60/10:18:e3:c4:d4/00:00:09:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq 8192 in
[  165.960118]          res 41/00:08:db:f5:30/00:00:08:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  165.960120] ata6.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  165.960122] ata6.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  165.960127] ata6.00: cmd 60/08:20:e3:dc:d4/00:00:09:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq 4096 in
[  165.960128]          res 41/00:08:db:f5:30/00:00:08:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  165.960131] ata6.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  165.960133] ata6.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  165.960138] ata6.00: cmd 60/18:28:db:dd:d4/00:00:09:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq 12288 in
[  165.960139]          res 41/00:08:db:f5:30/00:00:08:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  165.960141] ata6.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  165.960143] ata6.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  165.960148] ata6.00: cmd 60/18:40:d3:e3:d4/00:00:09:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq 12288 in
[  165.960149]          res 41/00:08:db:f5:30/00:00:08:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  165.960152] ata6.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  165.960158] ata6: hard resetting link
[  165.960159] ata6: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
[  166.432050] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[  166.788120] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  166.788142] ata6: EH complete
```

I would be grateful for any hints on how to fix the problem.

*T

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Yes, the user appears in the list. <sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0 does not fix the problem, so it might not be a permission issue?

Comment: I have connected serial over USB devices successfully in 16.04 and verified device output with Cutecom: maybe this will help if the device will broadcast

Comment: Have you added yourself to dialout group ?

Answer (score 1):

Add user to group dialout

```
sudo usermod -G dialout -a username
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention that you'll need to log out and log back in to have the membership become effective.

Answer (score 0):

As I see from logs, This GPS device doesn't not provide a storage interface that can be mount and browsed using file manage (`nautilus`).

You have to dedicated tools to read data from it via serial interface `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Try using `gpsbabel` it supports many protocol for GPS data collecting devices.

`Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x` is just the model & brand for the usb-serial converter. See [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/gpsbabel/mailman/message/23362786/), How you may check your GPS device.